# properly parse formatted currency in european form

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing, currency

Is there an easy/convinient way to parse a string for a price amount so it would detect if it is written in regular form, or in european form?

Regular:

```
"3,599.90"
```

Euro:

```
 "3.599,90"
```

both should be 3,599.90 after parsing

tests:

```
3.599,90 #=> 3599.90
3,599.90 #=> 3599.90
599.90 #=>  599.90
599,90 #=> 599.90
599 #=> 599
1,000,000 #=> 1000000
1.000.000 #=> 1000000
```

I could see if the `,` is before the `.` and infer on that, but what if the number is less than 4 digits? too many test cases.

Is there a better way to do this (in ruby)

Comment: just remove all periods and commas? Then divide by 100 for the decimal?

Comment: then I would need to detect if it has decimals or not. more test cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with [`money`](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem:

```
▶ "3,599.90".to_money
#⇒ #<Money fractional:359990 currency:USD>
▶ "3.599,90".to_money
#⇒ #<Money fractional:359990 currency:USD>
▶ "3.599,90".to_money.to_s
#⇒ "3599.90"
```